# Why isn't the dropdown menu working in my navbar when I click it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am practicing creating a navbar using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and the dropdown is not working when I click on it. I have my scripts referenced correctly and I have the latest version of jquery but its still not budging. The code is below. Can anyone help?

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="EN-US">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think bootstrap 3 has issues with jquery 3, change the version of jQuery to be either 1.12 or 2.x and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: What does the browser console tell you?

Comment: @epascarello yeah, apparently theres a problem with bootstrap 3 and jquery 3. I changed to jquery 2.2.4 and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't linked your resources properly. I tried it out and it worked. Maybe something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

You can always use a cdn link for bootstrap.

https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5f42fkcb/